# python urllib2 can't get google url

Tags: python, url, urllib2, urllib

I'm having a really tough time with getting the results page of this url with python's urllib2:

```
    http://www.google.com/search?tbs=sbi:AMhZZitAaz7goe6AsfVSmFw1sbwsmX0uIjeVnzKHjEXMck70H3j32Q-6FApxrhxdSyMo0OedyWkxk3-qYbyf0q1OqNspjLu8DlyNnWVbNjiKGo87QUjQHf2_1idZ1q_1vvm5gzOCMpChYiKsKYdMywOLjJzqmzYoJNOU2UsTs_1zZGWjU-LsjdFXt_1D5bDkuyRK0YbsaLVcx4eEk_1KMkcJpWlfFEfPMutxTLGf1zxD-9DFZDzNOODs0oj2j_1KG8FRCaMFnTzAfTdl7JfgaDf_1t5Vti8FnbeG9i7qt9wF6P-QK9mdvC15hZ5UR29eQdYbcD1e4woaOQCmg8Q1VLVPf4-kf8dAI7p3jM_1MkBBwaxdt_1TsM4FLwh0oHAYKOS5qBRI28Vs0aw5_1C5-WR4dC902Eqm5eAkLiQyAM9J2bioR66g3tMWe-j9Hyh1ID40R1NyXEJDHcGxp7xOn_16XxfW_1Cq5ArdSNzxFvABb1UcXCn5s4_1LpXZxhZbauwaO8cg3CKGLUvl_1wySDB7QIkMIF2ZInEPS4K-eyErVKqOdY9caYUD8X7oOf6sDKFjT7pNHwlkXiuYbKBRYjlvRHPlcPN1WHWCJWdSNyXdZhwDI3VRaKwmi4YNvkryeNMMbhGytfvlNaaelKcOzWbvzCtSNaP2lJziN1x3btcIAplPcoZxEpb0cDlQwId3A5FDhczxpVbdRnOB-Xeq_1AiUTt_1iI6bSgUAinWXQFYWveTOttdSNCgK-VTxV4OCtlrCrZerk27RBLAzT0ol9NOfYmYhiabzhUczWk4NuiVhKN-M4eo76cAsi74PY4V_1lWjvOpI35V_1YLJQrm0fxVcD34wxFYCIllT2gYW09fj3cuBDMNbsaJqPVQ04OOGlwmcmJeAnK96xd_1aMUd6FsVLOSDS7RfS5MNUSyd1jnXvRU_1MF_1Dj8oC8sm7PfVdjm3firiMcaKM28j9kGWbY0heIGLtO_1m6ad-iKfxYEzSux2b5w62LQlP57yS7vX8RFoyKzHA0RrFIEbPBQdNMA3Vpw0G_1LvEjCAPSCV1HH1pDp0l4EnNCvUIAppVXzNMyWT_1gKITj1NLqAn-Z1tH323JwZSc77OftDSreyHJ-BPxn3n7JMkNZFcQx6S7tfBxeqJ1NuDlpax11pw0_1Oi_1nF3vyEP0NbGKSVgNvBv_1tv8ahxvrHn9UnP78FleiOpzUBfdfRPZiT20VEq5-oXtV_1XwIzrd-5_15-cf2yoL7ohyPuv3WKGUGr4YCsYje7_1D8VslqMPsvbwMg9haj3TrBKH7go70ZfPjUv3h1K7lplnnCdV0hrYVQkSLUY1eEor3L--Vu5PlewS60ZH5YEn4qTnDxniV95h8q0Y3RWXJ6gIXitR5y6CofVg
```

I use the following headers, and this should be simple I would think:

```
    headers = {'Host':'www.google.com','User-Agent':user_agent,'Accept-Language':'en-us,en;q=0.5','Accept-Encoding':'gzip, deflate','Accept-Charset':'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7','Connection':'keep-alive','Referer':'http://www.google.co.in/imghp?hl=en&tab=ii','Cookie':'PREF=ID=1d7bc4ff2a5d8bc6:U=1d37ba5a518b9be1:FF=4:LD=en:TM=1300950025:LM=1302071720:S=rkk0IbbhxUIgpTyA; NID=51=uNq6mZ385WlV1UTfXsiWkSgnsa6PdjH4l9ph-vSQRszBHRcKW3VRJclZLd2XUEdZtxiCtl5hpbJiS3SpEV7670w_x738h75akcO6Viw47MUlpCZfy4KZ2vLT4tcleeiW; SID=DQAAAMEAAACoYm-3B2aiLKf0cRU8spJuiNjiXEQRyxsUZqKf8UXZXS55movrnTmfEcM6FYn-gALmyMPNRIwLDBojINzkv8doX69rUQ9-'}
```

When I do the following, I get a result that doesn't contain what any ordinary web browser returns:

```
    request=urllib2.Request(url,,None,headers)
    response=urllib2.urlopen(request)
    html=response.read()
```

Similarly, this bit of code returns a bunch of hex junk I can't read:

```
    request=urllib2.Request(url,headers=headers)
    response=urllib2.urlopen(request)
    html=response.read()
```

Please help, as I am quite sure this is simple enough, and I must just be missing something.  I was able to get this link in a similar way, but also uploading an image to images.google.com using the following code:

```
    import httplib, mimetypes, android, sys, urllib2, urllib, simplejson

    def post_multipart(host, selector, fields, files):
        """
        Post fields and files to an http host as multipart/form-data.
        fields is a sequence of (name, value) elements for regular form fields.
        files is a sequence of (name, filename, value) elements for data to be uploaded as files
        Return the server's response page.
        """
        content_type, body = encode_multipart_formdata(fields, files)
        h = httplib.HTTP(host)
        h.putrequest('POST', selector)
        h.putheader('content-type', content_type)
        h.putheader('content-length', str(len(body)))
        h.endheaders()
        h.send(body)
        errcode, errmsg, headers = h.getreply()
        return h.file.read()

    def encode_multipart_formdata(fields, files):
        """
        fields is a sequence of (name, value) elements for regular form fields.
        files is a sequence of (name, filename, value) elements for data to be uploaded as files
        Return (content_type, body) ready for httplib.HTTP instance
        """
        BOUNDARY = '----------ThIs_Is_tHe_bouNdaRY_$'
        CRLF = '\r\n'
        L = []
        for (key, value) in fields:
            L.append('--' + BOUNDARY)
            L.append('Content-Disposition: form-data; name="%s"' % key)
            L.append('')
            L.append(value)
        for (key, filename, value) in files:
            L.append('--' + BOUNDARY)
            L.append('Content-Disposition: form-data; name="%s"; filename="%s"' % (key, filename))
            L.append('Content-Type: %s' % get_content_type(filename))
            L.append('')
            L.append(value)
        L.append('--' + BOUNDARY + '--')
        L.append('')
        body = CRLF.join(L)
        content_type = 'multipart/form-data; boundary=%s' % BOUNDARY
        return content_type, body

    def get_content_type(filename):
        return mimetypes.guess_type(filename)[0] or 'application/octet-stream'


    host = 'www.google.co.in'
    selector = '/searchbyimage/upload'
    fields = [('user-agent','Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:6.0.2) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/6.0.2'),('connection','keep-alive'),('referer','')]

    with open('jpeg.jpg', 'rb') as jpeg:
        files = [('encoded_image', 'jpeg.jpg', jpeg.read())]
    response = post_multipart(host, selector, fields, files) #added: response = 
    responseLen=(len(response)-1)
    x=22
    if response[(x-21):(x+1)]!='EF=\"http://www.google':
       x+=1
    x+=145
    link=''
    while response[(x+1):(x+7)]!='amp;us':  #>here<
       link=link+response[x]
       x+=1
    print(link)
```

The above code returned not the page a browser would return, but instead html with a "link that has moved", which is the 'url' I posted first in this message.  If I can do the upload of my image and return a results page, why can't I get the resulting links html page?  It's severely frustrating:(

Please help, I've been burning out my brain for over a month on this problem.  Yes I am a newbee, but I thought this would be straightforward:(

Please help me to return the results page of this one little url:

```
    http://www.google.com/search?tbs=sbi:AMhZZitAaz7goe6AsfVSmFw1sbwsmX0uIjeVnzKHjEXMck70H3j32Q-6FApxrhxdSyMo0OedyWkxk3-qYbyf0q1OqNspjLu8DlyNnWVbNjiKGo87QUjQHf2_1idZ1q_1vvm5gzOCMpChYiKsKYdMywOLjJzqmzYoJNOU2UsTs_1zZGWjU-LsjdFXt_1D5bDkuyRK0YbsaLVcx4eEk_1KMkcJpWlfFEfPMutxTLGf1zxD-9DFZDzNOODs0oj2j_1KG8FRCaMFnTzAfTdl7JfgaDf_1t5Vti8FnbeG9i7qt9wF6P-QK9mdvC15hZ5UR29eQdYbcD1e4woaOQCmg8Q1VLVPf4-kf8dAI7p3jM_1MkBBwaxdt_1TsM4FLwh0oHAYKOS5qBRI28Vs0aw5_1C5-WR4dC902Eqm5eAkLiQyAM9J2bioR66g3tMWe-j9Hyh1ID40R1NyXEJDHcGxp7xOn_16XxfW_1Cq5ArdSNzxFvABb1UcXCn5s4_1LpXZxhZbauwaO8cg3CKGLUvl_1wySDB7QIkMIF2ZInEPS4K-eyErVKqOdY9caYUD8X7oOf6sDKFjT7pNHwlkXiuYbKBRYjlvRHPlcPN1WHWCJWdSNyXdZhwDI3VRaKwmi4YNvkryeNMMbhGytfvlNaaelKcOzWbvzCtSNaP2lJziN1x3btcIAplPcoZxEpb0cDlQwId3A5FDhczxpVbdRnOB-Xeq_1AiUTt_1iI6bSgUAinWXQFYWveTOttdSNCgK-VTxV4OCtlrCrZerk27RBLAzT0ol9NOfYmYhiabzhUczWk4NuiVhKN-M4eo76cAsi74PY4V_1lWjvOpI35V_1YLJQrm0fxVcD34wxFYCIllT2gYW09fj3cuBDMNbsaJqPVQ04OOGlwmcmJeAnK96xd_1aMUd6FsVLOSDS7RfS5MNUSyd1jnXvRU_1MF_1Dj8oC8sm7PfVdjm3firiMcaKM28j9kGWbY0heIGLtO_1m6ad-iKfxYEzSux2b5w62LQlP57yS7vX8RFoyKzHA0RrFIEbPBQdNMA3Vpw0G_1LvEjCAPSCV1HH1pDp0l4EnNCvUIAppVXzNMyWT_1gKITj1NLqAn-Z1tH323JwZSc77OftDSreyHJ-BPxn3n7JMkNZFcQx6S7tfBxeqJ1NuDlpax11pw0_1Oi_1nF3vyEP0NbGKSVgNvBv_1tv8ahxvrHn9UnP78FleiOpzUBfdfRPZiT20VEq5-oXtV_1XwIzrd-5_15-cf2yoL7ohyPuv3WKGUGr4YCsYje7_1D8VslqMPsvbwMg9haj3TrBKH7go70ZfPjUv3h1K7lplnnCdV0hrYVQkSLUY1eEor3L--Vu5PlewS60ZH5YEn4qTnDxniV95h8q0Y3RWXJ6gIXitR5y6CofVg
```

Dave

Comment: Why not use the [Google Custom Search API](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview) that they provide specially?

Comment: @katrielalex: that API only let's you search one specific website, not the general index. For that, there currently is only a deprecated API for JavaScript. The OP probably is trying to search the general index.

Comment: What did http://www.google.com/robots.txt tell you, and why do you think you can outsmart some of the best engineers in the world and trick them into letting you ignore it?

Answer (score 5):

Your user-agent is not defined !

Take that one :

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import urllib2

url = "http://www.google.com/search?q=mysearch";
opener = urllib2.build_opener()
opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]
print opener.open(url).read()
raw_input()
```

If you like find an other user-agent, you can write `about:config` in the Firefox.
And search "user-agent" :

> Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.7.8) Gecko/20050511
>
> Googlebot/2.1 (+http://www.google.com/bot.html)
>
> Opera/7.23 (Windows 98; U) [en]

Answer (score 0):

Google has several anti-scraping techniques in place, since they don't want users to get to the results without the APIs or real browsers.

If you are serious about scraping this kind of pages, I suggest you look into: [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) or [Spynner](http://code.google.com/p/spynner/).

Another advantage is that both execute javascript.

Comment: I will take a look at Selenium and Spynner.  My intent, however, is to use python standard libraries.  I will be implementing script so that it's cross platform and functional with android sl4a.  I'm following Googles Terms and Conditions, as the script is only run on individual instances by a user.