# 403 'Access Denied' Error when opening web page with urllib2 in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, urllib2, html, access-denied

I'm trying to get definitions of words using Google and urllib2 by opening this url, `https://www.google.com/search?q=define+<something>` and parsing the source for the definition. However, when I try to access the page I get a 403 Error, supposedly to prevent data mining in this sort of fasion. I'm fairly sure it wouldn't be wise to try and bypass that, so i'm wondering if there's an alternative for accessing data from Google's servers, or a data dump I should be using.

Edit: Here is the extent of the code i'm using to access the URL;

```
url = "https://www.google.com/search?q=define+" + word
try:
    source = ulib.urlopen(url)
except ulib.HTTPError, e:
    print e.fp.read()
```

Comment: We would need to check the code that you are using in order to see what is going wrong. A test on Chrome with that specific URL with a value for something does allow access.

Answer (score 1):

We would need to see your code for confirmation, but your question was probably answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11450649/python-urllib2-cant-get-google-url). In a nutshell, you need to define your user agent.